# Подскажите хорошие уроки по Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework, django-channels

Подскажите пожалуйста хорошие уроки по django channels с нуля, нигде не могу найти хорошую информацию, документация у них паленая(с ошибками и очень плохим объяснением), желательно если уроки или источник будет на русском, но можно и на английском.

Comment: Почему вы решили что с ошибками?

Comment: потому что там ошибки в импортах, ошибки в коде,  смотрел на django school и там автор делал так сказать обзор доков, если интересно - гляньте, там все он и рассказал

Comment: Почему вы решили, что там ошибки?

Comment: я же объяснил, посмотрите документацию, там в примере есть файл serializer, в остальных файлах он импрортируется неправильно, есть объект ws, который инициализирован в другом файле и не импортирован в другой, но в коде используется, и еще раз повторюсь, если хотите точнее увидеть это - посмотрите django school, на прямом эфире автор разбирал все эти ошибки

Comment: Вы о чём вообще? В документации Django Channels нету никакого serializer

Comment: извините, перепутал - в djangorestframework channels

Comment: Ну так это совершенно другая библиотека от совершенно других авторов. Исправьте вопрос, чтобы он содержал то, что вы на самом деле имеете в виду

Comment: А вот документация djangochannelsrestframework уже действительно [содержит ошибки](https://github.com/NilCoalescing/djangochannelsrestframework/issues/174), которые авторы ленятся исправить